# Handling Terraform provider credentials in distributed environment with InSpec and remote state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, test-kitchen, inspec

Does anyone have any cool ideas on how to handle Terraform provider credentials for AWS given these use cases:

- Distributed environments (prod/pre/qa/test/dev) with individual AWS accounts
- S3 backend remote state for all environments in a single AWS account
- Test Kitchen using InSpec.

My current workflow requires changing the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` depending on the operation:

- `terraform init` - requires access to S3 backend remote state
- `terraform plan/apply` - requires access to specific environment + remote state

  - Non-functional (a single set of credentials doesn't have access to both the env + remote state)
- `kitchen converge` - requires access to test environment + remote state

  - Non-functional (same reason as above)
- `kitchen verify` - requires access to test environment.

Ideas

- I wish I could store the S3 remote state in the respective environment accounts but variables don't seem to be supported in the Terraform `backend` configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the main account to be able to assume a role on each env account to perform the changes, while the remote main account will keep all states. This is a good way to work with terraform worspaces Assuming you have two workspaces, prod and dev, you can try something like this:

```
variable "workspace_roles" {
  default = {
    dev  = "arn:aws:iam::<dev account id>:role/terra_role"
    prod = "arn:aws:iam::<prodaccount id>:role/terra_role"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
 assume_role = var.workspace_roles[terraform.workspace]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this recommended elsewhere too.  It will be part of the solution.  I just need to figure out how to handle Kitchen since it uses either the AWS env vars or ~/.aws/credentials.

Comment: @XeonFibre you can pass `shared_credentials_profile` on kitchen config to specify the profile you want to use.